# Echo results from mysqli_Query

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm making a personal script for my own use, and I need to know how to echo the results from a mysqli_query. My code is as follows:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if(isset($_POST['commercial'])){
if (isset($_POST['0'])){
    $sql = "SELECT email FROM CommercialEmails WHERE articleid = '$_POST[article]' AND dripid = 1 AND sent='a'";
    $resultsd1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    echo $resultsd1;
}   
if (isset ($_POST['1'])){
    $sql = "SELECT email FROM CommercialEmails WHERE articleid = '$_POST[article]' AND dripid = 2 AND sent='a'";
    $resultsd2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    echo $resultsd2;
}   
if (isset($_POST['2'])){
    $sql = "SELECT email FROM CommercialEmails WHERE articleid = '$_POST[article]' AND dripid = 3 AND sent='a'";
    $resultsd3 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    echo $resultsd3;
}
if (isset ($_POST['3'])){
    $sql = "SELECT email FROM CommercialEmails WHERE articleid = '$_POST[article]' AND dripid = 4 AND sent='a'";
    $resultsd4 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    echo $resultsd4;
}
if (isset ($_POST['4'])){
    $sql = "SELECT email FROM CommercialEmails WHERE articleid = '$_POST[article]' AND dripid = 5 AND sent='a'";
    $resultsd5 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    echo $resultsd5;
}

}
?>
```

Comment: Sidenote: Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

Comment: I understand, this isn't going onto a web server, it's just for my own personal use, so I'm not worried about security much.

Comment: Read any tutorial on using MySQL from PHP: you have to call a "fetch" function to get the row contents.

Comment: echo results or the records?? bcoz the result you are echoing is just a boolean which returns true when a query is fired successfully.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php --- http://stackoverflow.com/q/20875113/

Comment: @habibulhaq It's not a boolean, it's a `mysqli_result` object that you can call `mysqli_fetch_array()` on.

Comment: @Barmar I thought it always worked like that. thanks for the guidence.

Comment: @habibulhaq For update queries it returns a boolean, for select it returns a result.

Comment: @Barmar we have to call mysqli_fetch_array() to get the records from result object.. can you tell me what only this result object holds??

Comment: It contains data used internally by the mysqli class.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to output multiple rows

```
if (isset($_POST['0'])) {
 $sql = "SELECT email FROM CommercialEmails WHERE articleid = '$_POST[article]' AND dripid = 1 AND sent='a'";
 $resultsd1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultsd1))
 {
    echo $row['email'];
 }
}
```

If only 1 row

```
if (isset($_POST['0'])){
 $sql = "SELECT email FROM CommercialEmails WHERE articleid = '$_POST[article]' AND dripid = 1 AND sent='a' LIMIT 1";
 $resultsd1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

 $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultsd1);

 echo $row['email'];
}
```

Comment: You have used `mysql_fetch_row` and referred it as `$row['email']` Check out my edit!

Answer (score 0):

First of all as @fred-ii said, escape your post, there is also an error in your $_POST access, you are missing quotes around article key, and lastly use mysqli_fetch_assoc to acces your results:

```
...
if (isset($_POST['0'])) {
    $article = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['article']);
    $sql = "SELECT email FROM CommercialEmails WHERE articleid = '$article' AND dripid = 1 AND sent='a'";
    if ($resultsd1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultsd1)) {
            echo $row['email'];
        }
    }
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply loop on the result object with `foreach` loop. If you want to fetch all the rows into a PHP variable you can use [`fetch_all()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php).

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT ...');
foreach($result as $row) {
    print_r($row);
    // do something with each row
}
// or
$result = $conn->('SELECT ...')->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
foreach($result as $row) {
    print_r($row);
    // do something with each row
}
```

However, in your case you should not be using `mysqli_query()` at all! This leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection. You must use parameter binding, which is available with prepared statements.

For example your fixed query would look like this:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT email FROM CommercialEmails WHERE articleid = ? AND dripid = 1 AND sent = 'a' ");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['article']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

The difference is that my variable is not separate from the SQL, so there is no risk of injection. You should never allow any variable input directly in SQL query. Doing this properly is really not that difficult.

Also, you don't really need to repeat the code so much. You can parameterize `dripid` too and reduce the number of lines in your code.