# I'm counting answers and I don't know how to automate this

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have answers from a database and i can count 1 now but i want to show the amount of times a answer is chosen. I have no qlue how to do that.
For instance I want to count the amount of times 'answer_id' (the id of the answer) 1 and 2 are answered in 'question_id'(the question)

I tried setting a different if while above it but that didn't work out for me.[image: The database]

```
<?php  
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','','survey_cms_4people');
if (!$conn){
    echo "DATABSE ERROR!";
}

$variable = 1;
$countAnswerQuery = "SELECT COUNT(`answer_id`) FROM survey_answers WHERE question_id=$variable AND answer_id=$variable ";
$countanswerresult = mysqli_query($conn, $countAnswerQuery);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($countanswerresult)) {
    echo $row[0];
}


?>
```

I want to be able to count them automaticly and not write a sql query for every question / answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to group by based on the answer id.

```
SELECT answer_id, COUNT(*) as count, question_id FROM survey_answers WHERE survey_id = $survey GROUP BY question_id , answer_id ORDER BY count DESC;
```

This will show you a count of all answers from all questions from a given survey.

This is probably a duplicate of:

[MySQL: Count the occurrences of DISTINCT values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346345/mysql-count-the-occurrences-of-distinct-values)

Comment: What is $survey?

Comment: $survey is a variable, the id of the survey you want the answers from.
I just noticed I made the group by wrong. question_id should be first, then answer_id. Edited*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29781511/echo-results-from-mysqli-query
Should give you all the info you need on getting results from your query.

Comment: but then it echo's two two numbers is it possible to show only one

Comment: You're echoing the whole row. You can select a certain value with row['count'], row['question_id'], row['answer_id'].

Comment: You should just follow a mysql php tutorial somewhere for this stuff.
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp

Answer (score 1):

> For instance I want to count the amount of times 'answer_id' (the id of the answer) 1 and 2 are answered in 'question_id'(the question)

You can aggregate the results by `question_id` and `answer_id` to find out how many time each answer was choosen for each question, like:

```
SELECT question_id, answer_id, COUNT(*) cnt
FROM survey_answers 
GOUP BY question_id, answer_id
```

If yiou want to filter on a given question, you can add a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT question_id, answer_id, COUNT(*) cnt
FROM survey_answers 
WHERE question_id = ?
GOUP BY question_id, answer_id
```